# Display issue: empty text field even though the value exists in the database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

"I am using **Room** for data persistence. Everything works fine except for this composable: *'TextFieldOptionList'*. The dropdown menu functionality works fine. When the user clicks on one of the items, the menu closes and the value appears in the text field. Then, if the user decides to save by pressing the *'FloatingActionButton'*, the values are sent correctly to 'firstSocialCategory' in the database (I checked with the App inspector).

The issue arises when clicking on the character card. When I arrive on the *'CharacterSheetScreen'* page, all fields display the values stored in the database, except for the *'TextFieldOptionList'* which is empty, even though the database contains the stored value."

```
object HomeScreenDestination : NavigationDestination {
    override val route = "character_screen"
    override val titleRes = "MES PERSONNAGES"
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    navigateToAddCharacter: (String, String) -> Unit,
    navigateToEditCharacter: (Int) -> Unit,
    homeViewModel: HomeViewModel = viewModel(factory = AppViewModelProvider.Factory)
) {
    val homeUiState by homeViewModel.homeUiState.collectAsState()
    var isAdding by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.enterAlwaysScrollBehavior()
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    Scaffold(
        modifier = modifier.nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection),
        topBar = {
            DeuxDesSixTopAppBar(
                title = HomeScreenDestination.titleRes,
                canNavigateBack = false
            )
        },
        floatingActionButton = {
            FloatingActionButton(
                onClick = {
                    isAdding = true
                },
                shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium,
            ) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.Add,
                    contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.add_character_content_description)
                )
            }
        }
    ) { innerPadding ->

        if (isAdding) {
            AddCharacterDialog(
                onConfirmClick = {
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        navigateToAddCharacter(it.name, it.level)
                    }
                },
                onCancel = { isAdding = false }
            )
        }

        CharacterBody(
            characterList = homeUiState.characterList,
            onCharacterClick = navigateToEditCharacter,
            onDeleteClick = { character ->
                homeViewModel.deleteCharacter(character)
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(innerPadding)
                .fillMaxSize()
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun CharacterInputForm(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    characterDetails: CharacterDetails,
    onValueChange: (CharacterDetails) -> Unit
) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    ) {
        Row {
            TextFieldCharacterInput(
                value = characterDetails.exp,
                onValueChange = { onValueChange(characterDetails.copy(exp = it)) },
                label = "XP ACQUIS",
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number,
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(10.dp))
            TextFieldCharacterInput(
                value = characterDetails.expStage,
                onValueChange = { onValueChange(characterDetails.copy(expStage = it)) },
                label = "PALIER",
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number,
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
            )
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
        Row {
            TextFieldCharacterInput(
                value = characterDetails.age,
                onValueChange = { onValueChange(characterDetails.copy(age = it)) },
                label = "AGE",
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number,
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(10.dp))
            TextFieldCharacterInput(
                value = characterDetails.height,
                onValueChange = { onValueChange(characterDetails.copy(height = it)) },
                label = "TAILLE",
                placeholder = "en cm",
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number,
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(10.dp))
            TextFieldCharacterInput(
                value = characterDetails.weight,
                onValueChange = { onValueChange(characterDetails.copy(weight = it)) },
                label = "POIDS",
                placeholder = "en kg",
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number,
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
            )
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
        Row {
            TextFieldCharacterInput(
                value = characterDetails.firstJob,
                onValueChange = { onValueChange(characterDetails.copy(firstJob = it)) },
                label = "MÉTIER 1",
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(10.dp))
            TextFieldCharacterInput(
                value = characterDetails.secondJob,
                onValueChange = { onValueChange(characterDetails.copy(secondJob = it)) },
                label = "MÉTIER 2",
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
            )
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
        TextFieldOptionList(
            optionList = socialCategory,
            optionValue = characterDetails.firstSocialCategory,
            onChangeValue = { onValueChange(characterDetails.copy(firstSocialCategory = it)) },
            label = "CAT. SOCIALE 1"
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
        TextFieldOptionList(
            optionList = socialCategory,
            optionValue = characterDetails.secondSocialCategory,
            onChangeValue = { onValueChange(characterDetails.copy(secondSocialCategory = it)) },
            label = "CAT. SOCIALE 2"
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
        Row {
            TextFieldCharacterInput(
                value = characterDetails.order,
                onValueChange = { onValueChange(characterDetails.copy(order = it)) },
                label = "ORDRE",
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(10.dp))
            TextFieldCharacterInput(
                value = characterDetails.religion,
                onValueChange = { onValueChange(characterDetails.copy(religion = it)) },
                label = "RELIGION",
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
            )
        }
    }
}

object CharacterSheetScreenDestination : NavigationDestination {
    override val route = "edit_character"
    override val titleRes = "MON PERSONNAGE"
    const val idArg = "character_id"
    val routeWithIdArg = "$route/{$idArg}"
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun CharacterSheetScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onNavigateUp : () -> Unit,
    characterSheetViewModel: CharacterSheetViewModel = viewModel(factory = AppViewModelProvider.Factory)
) {
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.enterAlwaysScrollBehavior()
    var selectedImageUri by remember { mutableStateOf<Uri?>(null) }
    val singlePhotoPickerLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia(),
        onResult = { uri ->
            selectedImageUri = uri
            characterSheetViewModel.updateUiState(
                characterSheetViewModel.uiState.characterDetails.copy(
                    imageCharacter = selectedImageUri
                )
            )
        }
    )

    Scaffold(
        modifier = modifier
            .nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection),
        topBar = {
            DeuxDesSixTopAppBar(
                title = characterSheetViewModel.uiState.characterDetails.name,
                canNavigateBack = true,
                navigateUp =  onNavigateUp
            )
        },
        floatingActionButton = {
            FloatingActionButton(
                onClick = {
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        characterSheetViewModel.updateCharacter()
                    }
                }
            ) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.Save,
                    contentDescription = "Edit your character"
                )
            }
        }
    ) { innerPadding ->
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(innerPadding),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            HeaderCharacterScreen(
                imageSelected = characterSheetViewModel.uiState.characterDetails.imageCharacter,
                onClickIconAddImage = {
                    singlePhotoPickerLauncher.launch(
                        PickVisualMediaRequest(
                            ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia.ImageOnly
                        )
                    )
                },
                level = characterSheetViewModel.uiState.characterDetails.level
            )
            CharacterInputForm(
                characterDetails = characterSheetViewModel.uiState.characterDetails,
                onValueChange = characterSheetViewModel::updateUiState,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(20.dp)
            )
        }
    }
}
```